# how to create column alias in select from database by redbeanphp?

Tags: php, mysql, redbean

i want to know how create a query such as this in redbeanphp:

```
select concat(first_name,' ',last_name) AS fullname from person;
```

i know redbean has a bindFunc Method but i do not know how to do this and this topic was not cover in redbean Documentation .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not use the bindFunc functions, they are not meant for these kind of things.
I recommend to use a FUSE model.

Just add a class named Model_Person (extends SimpleModel) docs: http://www.redbeanphp.com/models
Now add a method called getDisplayName() or something, inside this method you do something like:

public function getDisplayName() {
   return $this->bean->firstName . ' ' . $this->bean->lastName;
}

Now you can do this:

$person = R::load('person', $id);
echo $person->getDisplayName();

and it will show the full name...

Hope this helps, cheers
Gabor